# Is their any way to review a code in Xcode like eclipse IDE

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]like we can review the code in eclipse IDE. by the same way is their any tool to review the coding standard of a project like we the following coding standards

```
DATA-TYPE      USAGE      EXAMPLE
int             _i         _iMyNumber
float           _f         _fMyNumber
short           _s         _sMyShortVariable
double          _d         _dMyNumber
```

Comment: Forget eclipse, just tell us what you want to do. "review a code" needs some explanation.

Comment: @Zaph- if someone has not used coding standards than it will be highlighted or show warnings suppose if i use int anynumber; in place of _iMyNumber then warning can be seen in Xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using _iMyNumber instead of myNumber is a coding standard and there is no capability in Xcode to detect that. But it is a bad coding standard based in the past when compilers and IDEs were less capable.

Don't do it, it just makes the code harder to read, it is much better to use very descriptive names for variables and method names, descriptive to what they contain, not their type. Xcode can detect incorrect assignments and warn. It is very rare to see such code in Objective-C.